# If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^1$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and rank$(Df_a) = m$, prove or disprove the following:

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^1$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and  rank$(Df_a) = m$, then there exists $\epsilon > 0$, such that $B_\epsilon (f(a)) \subseteq f(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

My first instinct is to use Taylor's Theorem and try $f(a+h)-f(a) = Df_a (h) + r(h)$ and see if I can turn $f(a+h) - f(a)$ into some ball of radius epsilon using the fact that $Df_a$ is onto but I really have no clue how to proceed from here.

Comment: Do you know the [implicit function theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)?

Comment: I know the implicit function theorem but I tried to apply it here and didn't see it getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a linear subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ such that $Df_a$ is a linear isomorphism from $V$ onto $\mathbb R^m$. Then take $H \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ with $H \oplus V=\mathbb R^n$. You can find a unique $(h_a,v_a) \in H \times V$ with $a=h_a +v_a$

Now define $$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\bar{f} : & V & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R ^m\\
    & v & \longmapsto & f(h_a+v)\end{array}$$

$D\bar{f}_{v_a}$ is invertible and you can apply the inverse function theorem to get the desired result.

Comment: I did end up using this strategy and I believe I have solved it. I defined $\widetilde{f}$: m-plane $\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that this map was invertible and used the inverse function theorem like you said to get an open mapping. Thank you for the suggestion.